# How to fix "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string" error?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm getting the following error.
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use("view engine", "jade");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.send("Hello");

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  //useNewUrlParser: true,
    //    useUnifiedTopology: true,S
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `app.set` instead of `app.use`?

Comment: Also, it is not necessary to load the `bodyParser` module yourself as it's already built into Express.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
app.use("view engine", "jade");
```

should be:

```
app.set("view engine", "jade");
```

---

`app.use()` is for middleware and requires the second argument to be a function and the error is telling you that it found a string there instead of a function.

It has a calling signature of:

```
app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])
```

which means it can be like these:

```
app.use("/somepath", fn1);
app.use(fn1);
app.use(fn1, fn2);
```

It can't be:

```
app.use("somestring", "otherstring");
```

Which is why you get an error when you try to use it with two strings.